# The space in the others section of iTunes is taking 1.85GB

Tags: itunes, ios, ipod-touch

I have an iPod touch 4g on iOS 6.0.1; 8GB. The others section in iTunes takes 1.99GB. I don't have more than 20 contacts, no email accounts, and not more than 5 notes.

First what I backed up and restored my iPod and again restored from my backup to get my apps again. I did this 5 times and Others remained at 1.99GB.

NOTE: **I don't have any music and removed all mail, music, and contacts for this.**

I tried deleting the music folders of iTunes from diskaid and Others dropped to 1.85GB. That still seems like too much.

What should I do?

UPDATE: i dont have any big apps except FIFA 13. All othersare less than 100MB each. Excluding FIFA 13 all the other apps and photos takes 547MB.

Answer (score 1):

Even with 10 apps, make sure none of them is containing lots of documents (e.g., an eBook or comic book reader).

Or download [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) (free for file system access) and browse through the content of your device.

Also, you can try this:

- Connect your device to the computer.
- Open iTunes and select it.
- Go to the *Applications* tab.
- Scroll down to the *Share Files* section and.
- Select every app one by one and see what documents can be transferred to your computer (you'll be able to check its size).

Comment: i have adobe reader with 3 files and thats it. none of them over 5 mb. i will try iexplorer.

Comment: what should i delete through iexplorer?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use iExplorer to delete files. It doesn't try to be a _Clean My Mac_ for iOS devices. I mentioned iExplorer so that you can browse and see what is taking a lot of space. Do it via your iPod Touch. If it's not possible, then it's probably a system file you shouldn't delete.

Comment: i didnt get anything useless..:(......so what should i do now....idea..?

Comment: See [this](http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/25/what-is-the-iphone-other-capacity-seen-in-itunes/) and [this](http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/12/force-ios-devices-to-recalculate-other-capacity-in-itunes/). And go to your device Settings->General->Information and see if it shows a different amount of available space compared to what it shows in iTunes.

Comment: the first i have seen it before. i tried the second one you told to see but didnt work. in ipod the available space is 2.1 gb while in itunes it is 2.2 gb.